# A weird crash error in GDB

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, sigabrt

I tried debugging this program in GDB but I get an extremely weird crash error (SIGABRT). It happens in my pop function but I have no idea why. Can someone help me? Thanks alot!

I stepped through GDB and I believe the crash happens when i = 9 and at free(tmp) in the pop function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE  1


struct linkedStruct
{
    int elem;
    struct linkedStruct*  next;
};

typedef struct linkedStruct linked;
typedef linked* linkedPtr;

void push (linkedPtr* hd, int val)
{
    linkedPtr ptr = (linkedPtr) malloc (sizeof(linked));
    ptr->elem = val;
    ptr->next = *hd;
    *hd = ptr;
}

int isEmpty (linkedPtr hd)
{
    if (hd == NULL)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}


int top (linkedPtr hd)
{
    return (hd->elem);
}

void pop (linkedPtr hd)
{
    linkedPtr tmp = hd;
    hd = hd->next;
    free (tmp);
}

void show (linkedPtr hd)
{
    while (hd != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%d, ", hd->elem);
        hd = hd->next;
    }
    printf ("\n");
}

int main (int argc, char**argv)
{
    linkedPtr head = NULL;
    int i;
    int temp;

  /* push 10 random values onto the stack showing the stack growing */
    for (i = 0 ; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        temp = rand() % 100;
        printf ("In main(): temp: %6d\n", temp);
        push (&head, temp);
        show (head);
    }

    printf ("\n");

  /* remove the value from the stack */
    while (!isEmpty(head))
    {
        printf ("Top of stack value is: %d\n", top(head));
        pop (head);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: what happens, when there's only one element?

Comment: You know that any changes on `hd` (like `hd = hd->next;`) won't be maintained after `pop()` finishes, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem here is that changes to `hd` are not visible to the caller, which leads to `free()` being called on the memory that has already been freed and thus it produces **undefined behavior**.

Your `pop()` should look like this:

```
void pop (linkedPtr* hd)
{
    linkedPtr tmp = *hd;
    *hd = (*hd)->next;
    free (tmp);
}
```

and called like this:

```
pop(&head);
```

Comment: `pop()` won't change `hd` since it's passed by value.

Comment: @m0skit0: Yeah, I've noticed that too, just a bit late. Assigning `next` to the passed pointer is desired here, since it is a way of passing `NULL` to the caller.